# Finding all permutations of numbers plucked from an array which sum to 16

Tags: arrays, ruby, circular-permutations

I would like to find all the permutations of plucking 3, 4 or 5 numbers from [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], repeats allowed, such that their sum is 16. So [8,5,3], [8,3,5] and [4,3,3,3,3] are valid permutations. Also circular permutations should be removed so [3,3,3,3,4] wouldn't also be added to the answer. 
I can do this in Ruby without allowing repeats like this:

```
d = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
number_of_divisions = [3,4,5]
number_of_divisions.collect do |n|
  d.permutation(n).to_a.reject do |p|
    p[0..n].inject(0) { |sum,x| sum + x } != 16
  end
end
```

How could I allow repeats so that [3,3,3,3,4] was included?

Comment: [`Array#repeated_permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation).

Comment: Are the numbers necessarily non-negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *all* permutations, including duplicates, one might use [`Array#repeated_permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation):

```
d = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
number_of_divisions = [3,4,5]
number_of_divisions.flat_map do |n|
  d.repeated_permutation(n).reject do |p| # no need `to_a`
    p.inject(:+) != 16
  end
end
```

or, even better with [`Array#repeated_combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination):

```
number_of_divisions.flat_map do |n|
  d.repeated_combination(n).reject do |p| # no need `to_a`
    p.inject(:+) != 16
  end
end
```

Comment: You can avoid using `map(&:sort)` and `uniq` by using `repeated_combination` instead.

Comment: `repeated_permutation` and `repeated_combination` are just the ticket! Thanks guys

Comment: @iceツ indeed. Updated an answer.

Comment: On second thoughts... The OP is clearly interested in permutations (where position matters i.e. `[8,3,5]` and `[8,5,3]` are valid) but your answer converts to combinations i.e. `[8,3,5]` and `[8,5,3]` are considered the same. So it may be best to leave your original answer except remove the `map` and `uniq`.

Comment: With `d = [2,3,4,5]; number_of_divisions = [3]` and the desired sum `12` (rather than `16`), both snippets return `[[2, 5, 5], [3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4]]`, which is missing `[3,5,4]`. In #1 the problem is that `sort` followed by `uniq` removes too much, and in #2, `repeated_combination` will return arrays `a` such that if `i < j`, `d[i]` will always precede `d[j]` in the elements returned by `repeated_combination` that contain both of those elements of `d`. If, for example, `d` is sorted, all of the combinations will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

There are far fewer repeated combinations than repeated permutations, so let's find the repeated combinations that sum to the given value, then permute each of those. Moreover, by applying `uniq` at each of several steps of the calculation we can significantly reduce the number of repeated combinations and permutations considered.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def rep_perms_for_all(arr, n_arr, tot)
  n_arr.flat_map { |n| rep_perms_for_1(arr, n, tot) }
end

def rep_perms_for_1(arr, n, tot)
   rep_combs_to_rep_perms(rep_combs_for_1(arr, n, tot)).uniq
end

def rep_combs_for_1(arr, n, tot)
  arr.repeated_combination(n).uniq.select { |c| c.sum == tot }
end

def rep_combs_to_rep_perms(combs)
  combs.flat_map { |c| comb_to_perms(c) }.uniq
end

def comb_to_perms(comb)
  comb.permutation(comb.size).uniq.uniq do |p| 
    p.size.times.with_object(Set.new) { |i,s| s << p.rotate(i) } 
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
rep_perms_for_all([2,3,4,5], [3], 12)
  #=> [[2, 5, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 5, 4], [4, 4, 4]]
rep_perms_for_all([2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [3,4,5], 16).size
  #=> 93
rep_perms_for_all([2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [3,4,5], 16)
  #=> [[2, 6, 8], [2, 8, 6], [2, 7, 7], [3, 5, 8], [3, 8, 5], [3, 6, 7],
  #    [3, 7, 6], [4, 4, 8], [4, 5, 7], [4, 7, 5], [4, 6, 6], [5, 5, 6],
  #    [2, 2, 4, 8], [2, 2, 8, 4], [2, 4, 2, 8], [2, 2, 5, 7], [2, 2, 7, 5],
  #    [2, 5, 2, 7], [2, 2, 6, 6], [2, 6, 2, 6], [2, 3, 3, 8], [2, 3, 8, 3], 
  #    ...
  #    [3, 3, 3, 7], [3, 3, 4, 6], [3, 3, 6, 4], [3, 4, 3, 6], [3, 3, 5, 5], 
  #    [3, 5, 3, 5], [3, 4, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 4], [3, 5, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4, 4],
  #    ...
  #    [2, 2, 4, 5, 3], [2, 2, 5, 3, 4], [2, 2, 5, 4, 3], [2, 3, 2, 4, 5],
  #    [2, 3, 2, 5, 4], [2, 3, 4, 2, 5], [2, 3, 5, 2, 4], [2, 4, 2, 5, 3],
  #    ...
  #    [2, 5, 3, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [2, 3, 4, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 4, 3],
  #    [2, 4, 3, 3, 4], [2, 4, 3, 4, 3], [2, 4, 4, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 4]]
```

**Explanation**

`rep_combs_for_1` uses the method [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum), which made its debut in Ruby v2.4. For earlier versions, use `c.reduce(:0) == tot`.

In `comb_to_perms`, the first `uniq` simply removes duplicates. The second `uniq`, with a block, removes all but one of the `p.size` elements (arrays) that can be obtained by rotating any of the other `p-1` elements. For example,

```
p = [1,2,3]
p.size.times.with_object(Set.new) { |i,s| s << p.rotate(i) }
  #=> #<Set: {[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]}>
```

Comment: This is very interesting.  I had wondered if the previous solutions were including too few results but couldn't spot one that was missing.